# WPF: Listbox, centering selected item

Tags: wpf, listbox, scroll, selecteditem

Is it possible to always keep selected item in the middle of a listbox? If the user selects an item, I want to scroll so that the newly selected item is in the middle.

I guess it want be possible for the 'edge cases' (the first and last few items), but that's ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

David Anson posted some articles on his blog that might help you here: [Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/03/30/don-t-let-the-gotchas-getcha-adding-the-scrollintoviewcentered-method-to-wpf-s-listbox.aspx) and [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/04/19/fewer-gotchas-to-getcha-enhancing-the-scrollintoviewcentered-method-for-wpf-s-listbox.aspx). He gives an extension method that centers an item in an List Box. You might be able to build on that.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with couple of lines of custom code. Here's a discussion of a [sample implementation](http://blogs.jp.infragistics.com/blogs/ctaylor/archive/2008/06/17/carousel-listbox-selection.aspx). You might need to tweak it a bit to account for even number of items, insted of only odd number, but the general idea is the same.

Comment: The CarouselListBox seems to include a lot of properties that I cant find on a regular ListBox. How can i get the ScrollViewer for my listbox?