# wxWidgets ComboBox center on selected item

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a requirement to center a wx.ComboBox on the selected item when opened. 
Basically, I want to do this ([WPF: Listbox, centering selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592911/wpf-listbox-centering-selected-item)), but using wxWidgets.

Thanks

Comment: You mean pre-selection of ComboBox option when dialog is shown, right?

Comment: Or do you mean to center the combobox in the sizer in the layout?  Or do you mean to center the text within the combobox?

Comment: The example you link is not for a Combobox but for a ListBox . afaik the list in a combobox does not have a vertical scroll bar as in ListBoxes so it is difficult to know what are you asking for without additional info from your side.