# ScrollIntoView - item should not disapear from view

Tags: c#, wpf

From the start I wanna say I will award a 200 Bounty to somebody who can help me with my problem.

This is my simple code(C# with WPF):

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        string fixedItem;

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventHandler(list_changes);

        }



        private void list_changes(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.ScrollIntoView(fixedItem);
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {      
            fixedItem = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem;        
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("item0");
            listBox1.Items.Add("item1");
            listBox1.Items.Add("item2");
            listBox1.Items.Add("item3");
            listBox1.Items.Add("item4");
            listBox1.Items.Add("item5");
            listBox1.Items.Add("item6");

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item7");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item8");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item9");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item10");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item11");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item12");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item13");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item14");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item15");
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item16");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item17");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item18");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item19");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item20");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item21");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item22");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item23");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item24");
        }
    }
}
```

First I just made 3 Buttons to insert some text in the listBox. Lets say I click button1 and button2, I will have this list:

```
item15
item14
item13
item12
......
item7
item0
item1
.....
item6
```

After that I want to click on "item12", then when I click button3 I want my "item12" to remain in the same spot while the text is generated(4th position in the list).
In short words everytime I click on item I want it to remain in the exctly same position while generating text.

So anyone has any idee how to do this ? Do I need to use ScrollViewer object to work with VerticallOffset and ViewportHeigth ? This simple code that I posted when I click on the item and then generate text it will move the item at the bottom(viewable position) and remains there after. But I don't want to move it at all.

Edit:

Ok I tried this code from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/04/19/fewer-gotchas-to-getcha-enhancing-the-scrollintoviewcentered-method-for-wpf-s-listbox.aspx):

```
FrameworkElement container = listRadioItems.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(fixedItem) as FrameworkElement;

            if (null != container)
            {
                if (ScrollViewer.GetCanContentScroll(listBox))
                {
                    IScrollInfo scrollInfo = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(container) as IScrollInfo;
                    if (null != scrollInfo)
                    {
                        StackPanel stackPanel = scrollInfo as StackPanel;
                        VirtualizingStackPanel virtualizingStackpanel = scrollInfo as VirtualizingStackPanel;

                        int index = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(container);

                        if (((null != stackPanel) && (Orientation.Horizontal == stackPanel.Orientation)) || ((null != virtualizingStackpanel) && (Orientation.Horizontal == virtualizingStackpanel.Orientation)))
                        {
                            scrollInfo.SetHorizontalOffset(index - Math.Floor(scrollInfo.ViewportWidth / 2));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            scrollInfo.SetVerticalOffset(index - Math.Floor(scrollInfo.ViewportHeight / 2));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Rect rect = new Rect(new Point(), container.RenderSize);

                    FrameworkElement constrainingParent = container;
                    do
                    {
                        constrainingParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(constrainingParent) as FrameworkElement;
                    } while ((null != constrainingParent) && (listBox != constrainingParent) && !(constrainingParent is ScrollContentPresenter));

                    if (null != constrainingParent)
                    {
                        rect.Inflate(Math.Max((constrainingParent.ActualWidth - rect.Width) / 2, 0), Math.Max((constrainingParent.ActualHeight - rect.Height) / 2, 0));
                    }

                    container.BringIntoView(rect);
                }
            }
```

What it does for me is it centeres the item selected, but the scroll goes down, only sometimes it also centeres. And my problem is that again, only sometimes the selected item will disapear from view.

What would be fantastic is if I can make both the item and the scroll centered. But first concern is the item should not disapear from view.

Comment: you said your selected item is moved to the button and you dont want this. why you add new items with index 0 to the collection? so the new items will always the first... maybe you sould explain want you want to achieve. the easy way is to take an index higher then the selecteditem index.

Comment: well yes, thats the point, the scrollbar should move down so that the item selected seems to be in the same position, altough there are other elements inserted above it

Comment: look at the link i posted in my answer maybe it helps you.

Comment: @vBx i think you idea is right about the offset valeus bc the offset is only hold the actual position try to implement it with offset values it will work insteed of scrolling into items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that gets the first visible item in your ListBox, adds the items to whatever index you specify, then uses the Dispatcher to scroll the list back to the first visible item after all the new items have been rendered.

The `ScrollIntoViewTop()` extension method is the same method as the link you posted in your original question, but I altered it to leave the item at the top of the list.

The `WPFHelpers.IsObjectVisibleInContainer()` method is one I've used in the past to test if an object is fully or partially visible within another container. To get the first visible item, I simply loop through the ListBox items, get the ListBoxItem container associated with each item, then check if that container is visible or not. The first one that returns true is the first visible item in the ListBox.

Here's the full code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var firstVisibleItem = GetFirstVisibleItem(listBox1);

        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item0");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item1");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item2");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item3");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item4");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item5");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item6");

        if (firstVisibleItem != null)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
                new Action(delegate()
                {
                    listBox1.ScrollIntoViewTop(firstVisibleItem);
                }));
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var firstVisibleItem = GetFirstVisibleItem(listBox1);

        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item7");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item8");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item9");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item10");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item11");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item12");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item13");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item14");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item15");

        if (firstVisibleItem != null)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
                new Action(delegate()
                {
                    listBox1.ScrollIntoViewTop(firstVisibleItem);
                }));
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var firstVisibleItem = GetFirstVisibleItem(listBox1);

        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item16");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item17");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item18");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item19");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item20");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item21");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item22");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item23");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item24");

        if (firstVisibleItem != null)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
                new Action(delegate()
                {
                    listBox1.ScrollIntoViewTop(firstVisibleItem);
                }));
        }
    }

    private object GetFirstVisibleItem(ListBox listBox)
    {
        foreach (var item in listBox.Items)
        {
            var itemContainer = (ListBoxItem)listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);

            if (WPFHelpers.IsObjectVisibleInContainer(itemContainer, listBox) == ControlVisibility.Full)
            {
                return item;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public enum ControlVisibility
{
    Hidden,
    Partial,
    Full,
    FullHeightPartialWidth,
    FullWidthPartialHeight
}

public class WPFHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks to see if an object is rendered visible within a parent container
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="child">UI element of child object</param>
    /// <param name="parent">UI Element of parent object</param>
    /// <returns>ControlVisibility Enum: Hidden, Partial or Visible</returns>
    public static ControlVisibility IsObjectVisibleInContainer(FrameworkElement child, UIElement parent)
    {
        GeneralTransform childTransform = child.TransformToAncestor(parent);
        //Rect childSize = childTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), child.RenderSize));
        Rect childSize = childTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(child.ActualWidth, child.ActualHeight)));

        Rect result = Rect.Intersect(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), parent.RenderSize), childSize);
        if (result == Rect.Empty)
        {
            return ControlVisibility.Hidden;
        }
        if (result.Height == childSize.Height && result.Width == childSize.Width)
        {
            return ControlVisibility.Full;
        }
        if (result.Height == childSize.Height)
        {
            return ControlVisibility.FullHeightPartialWidth;
        }
        if (result.Width == childSize.Width)
        {
            return ControlVisibility.FullWidthPartialHeight;
        }
        return ControlVisibility.Partial;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Class implementing helpful extensions to ListBox.
/// </summary>
public static class ListBoxExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Causes the object to scroll into view centered.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listBox">ListBox instance.</param>
    /// <param name="item">Object to scroll.</param>
    //[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1011:ConsiderPassingBaseTypesAsParameters",
    //    Justification = "Deliberately targeting ListBox.")]
    public static void ScrollIntoViewTop(this ListBox listBox, object item)
    {
        Debug.Assert(!VirtualizingStackPanel.GetIsVirtualizing(listBox),
            "VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing must be disabled for ScrollIntoViewCentered to work.");

        // Get the container for the specified item
        var container = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as FrameworkElement;
        if (null != container)
        {
            if (ScrollViewer.GetCanContentScroll(listBox))
            {
                // Get the parent IScrollInfo
                var scrollInfo = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(container) as IScrollInfo;
                if (null != scrollInfo)
                {
                    // Need to know orientation, so parent must be a known type
                    var stackPanel = scrollInfo as StackPanel;
                    var virtualizingStackPanel = scrollInfo as VirtualizingStackPanel;
                    Debug.Assert((null != stackPanel) || (null != virtualizingStackPanel),
                        "ItemsPanel must be a StackPanel or VirtualizingStackPanel for ScrollIntoViewCentered to work.");

                    // Get the container's index
                    var index = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(container);

                    // Center the item by splitting the extra space
                    if (((null != stackPanel) && (Orientation.Horizontal == stackPanel.Orientation)) ||
                        ((null != virtualizingStackPanel) && (Orientation.Horizontal == virtualizingStackPanel.Orientation)))
                    {
                        //scrollInfo.SetHorizontalOffset(index - Math.Floor(scrollInfo.ViewportWidth / 2));
                        scrollInfo.SetHorizontalOffset(index);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //scrollInfo.SetVerticalOffset(index - Math.Floor(scrollInfo.ViewportHeight / 2));
                        scrollInfo.SetVerticalOffset(index);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Get the bounds of the item container
                var rect = new Rect(new Point(), container.RenderSize);

                // Find constraining parent (either the nearest ScrollContentPresenter or the ListBox itself)
                FrameworkElement constrainingParent = container;
                do
                {
                    constrainingParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(constrainingParent) as FrameworkElement;
                } while ((null != constrainingParent) &&
                         (listBox != constrainingParent) &&
                         !(constrainingParent is ScrollContentPresenter));

                if (null != constrainingParent)
                {
                    // Inflate rect to fill the constraining parent
                    rect.Inflate(
                        Math.Max((constrainingParent.ActualWidth - rect.Width) / 2, 0),
                        Math.Max((constrainingParent.ActualHeight - rect.Height) / 2, 0));
                }

                // Bring the (inflated) bounds into view
                container.BringIntoView(rect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rachel, the BeginInvoke part has to be in the same function where the adding of the items takes place ? Because in my real program  the adding part is done from C++.

Comment: @vBx It can be called from anywhere that has access the current Application's `Dispatcher`. For example, you could go `ListBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);` instead

Comment: Ok, I will try it tomorrow at work, and let you know. My concern is that while items are added the add function is blocking and I can't select any item while generating, only after. I read somewhere that I need to use BeginInvoke like you did, I hope this works for me(quite new to c# & wpf)

Comment: so that is my problem, I can't select items while they are added, because the add function is blocking...I have something like this in my code: ObservableCollection<Items> addItems;  addItems.add(item); in short...I guess I would need t make this async ? any idee how ? Or you have another solution ?

Comment: ok, fixed that, my only problem no wis that after i select, and want to move the scroll lets say up, it will go back again to the selected item, i dont want that

Comment: @vBx See my updated answer. I altered the code so the ListBox scrolls back to show the same items as before.

Comment: My concern with this solution is that it requires disabling virtualization of the panel. This could be an issue with panels that have enough items for virtualization to be important. I have a slightly different goal: I simply want to scroll to the bottom and/or to a specific index. I was able to solve it by searching the visual tree for the `VirtualizingPanel` and calling its `BringIndexIntoViewPublic()` method. But I prefer solutions that don't require digging around in the visual tree to pull out what I want; do you know of a cleaner approach that is still virtualizing-compatible?

Answer (score 1):

do you want to select "item12" - then add more items - and after this "item12" should still be selected and in view?

if yes why not use [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx).MoveTo method after adding new items? you just have to remember the last selected items before adding new items.

i use MoveTo and ScrollIntoView in my projects, it works fine.

EDIT:

i do not add items directly to the listbox. i use a collection and add this collection to the itemssource of the listbox. i use the SelectionChanged event for ScrollItemsIntoView.

```
 var _myview = (ICollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this._mycollection);

 _myview.MoveCurrentTo(this.rememberredItem);
```

if you work with Ado.net collections then you have to take BindingListCollectionView instead of ICollectionView

EDIT2:
instead of CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listBox1.ItemsSource) you could try the following. create a observablecollection and set the collection as itemssource for your listbox.

```
ICollectionView myview;
OberservableCollection<string> mysource = new ObservableCollection<string>();
myview = (ICollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.mysource);
listbox1.ItemsSource = mysource; //you should better use binding in xaml here
```

if you want to add items now just add it to the collection.

```
this.mysource.Add("Item 13");
this.mysource.Add("Item 14");
```

EDIT3: copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592911/wpf-listbox-centering-selected-item)

> David Anson posted some articles on his blog that might help you here: Part 1 and Part 2. He gives an extension method that centers an item in an List Box. You might be able to build on that

Comment: So I should call this MoveCurrentTo in method where list items changes and ScrollIntoView in to the SelectionChanged event ?

Comment: thats the way i do it im my project. after add items to my collection i call MoveCurrentTo(...). the ScrollIntoView method is called in the SelectionChanged handler.

Comment: I use this line: ListCollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listBox1.ItemsSource) as ListCollectionView; but it always returns null. Any idee why ?

Comment: see Edit2. i always use a collection as an ItemsSource and do not add items directly.

Answer (score 1):

I made few changes to your code, please have a look.

Before adding items on button 2 and button 3 click... i am getting fixeditem and fixed item index and rearranging the fixed item after adding items....

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        string fixedItem;
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventHandler(list_changes);
        }



        private void list_changes(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.ScrollIntoView(fixedItem);
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //fixedItem = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("item0");
            listBox1.Items.Add("item1");
            listBox1.Items.Add("item2");
            listBox1.Items.Add("item3");
            listBox1.Items.Add("item4");
            listBox1.Items.Add("item5");
            listBox1.Items.Add("item6");

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            fixedItem = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem;
            int selectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;

            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item7");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item8");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item9");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item10");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item11");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item12");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item13");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item14");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item15");

            listBox1.Items.Remove(fixedItem);
            listBox1.Items.Insert(selectedIndex, fixedItem);
            listBox1.SelectedItem = fixedItem;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            fixedItem = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem;
            int selectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;

            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item16");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item17");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item18");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item19");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item20");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item21");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item22");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item23");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "item24");

            listBox1.Items.Remove(fixedItem);
            listBox1.Items.Insert(selectedIndex, fixedItem);
            listBox1.SelectedItem = fixedItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Update with Reference Type:
I created a class called item.. instead of adding string i am adding item...

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        Item fixedItem;
        int selectedIndex;
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventHandler(list_changes);
        }



        private void list_changes(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(new Item { ItemName = "item0" });
            listBox1.Items.Add(new Item { ItemName = "item1" });
            listBox1.Items.Add(new Item { ItemName = "item2" });
            listBox1.Items.Add(new Item { ItemName = "item3" });
            listBox1.Items.Add(new Item { ItemName = "item4" });
            listBox1.Items.Add(new Item { ItemName = "item5" });
            listBox1.Items.Add(new Item { ItemName = "item6" });
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                fixedItem = (Item)listBox1.SelectedItem;
                selectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            }
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item7" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item8" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item9" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item10" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item11" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item12" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item13" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item14" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item15" });

            listBox1.Items.Remove(fixedItem);
            listBox1.Items.Insert(selectedIndex, fixedItem);
            listBox1.SelectedItem = fixedItem;
            listBox1.ScrollIntoView(fixedItem);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                fixedItem = (Item)listBox1.SelectedItem;
                selectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            }

            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item16" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item17" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item18" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item19" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item20" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item21" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item22" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item23" });
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, new Item { ItemName = "item24" });

            listBox1.Items.Remove(fixedItem);
            listBox1.Items.Insert(selectedIndex, fixedItem);
            listBox1.SelectedItem = fixedItem;
            listBox1.ScrollIntoView(fixedItem);
        }
    }

    class Item
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

XAML Change....

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" Height="300" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: It kinda works, but when I choose another selected item, then again, same problem. My sugestion is that the code shoud not have anything to do with the buttons, because in my real project the generated elements are coming from the internet, I just put the buttons for simulation

Comment: I understand that the buttons are for stimulating... what i mean in the solution is ... instead of doing some thing in events we have to apply logic before and after adding the items..  that's why i have added some code before adding the items and after adding items... and  in real project you can do some thing similar to this before getting items from internet and after adding them...and i really don't understand " but when I choose another selected item, then again, same problem" in your comment.

Comment: what I mean is: I choose item12 then  i press button1, button2, button3, all of them, all good, but then if I choose another item and start pressing the buttons again, it moves again

Comment: That is because of using value types (in your case strings).. it will not happen if you use reference type. i am going to update the answer with reference type...

Comment: Yes, I saw, still thinkin a way to do it without adding code where elements are generated...Im looking into ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working just hold the postion untill you menual changes the selected item.

XAML Code

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="189*" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="72*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" Grid.Row="0" />
        <Button Click="Button_Click"  Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
```

C# code

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.Items.Count <= 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
                {
                    ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
                    item.Content = "Content " + i;
                    listBox1.Items.Insert(i, item);
                  //  listBox1.SelectedItem = item;
                }
                listBox1.SelectedItem = listBox1.Items[12];
            }
            else
            {
                ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
                item.Content = "Content " + listBox1.Items.Count;
                listBox1.Items.Insert(listBox1.Items.Count, item);
              //  listBox1.SelectedItem = item;
            }

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
                new Action(delegate()
                {
                    listBox1.ScrollIntoView(listBox1.SelectedItem);
                }));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
namespace WpfApplication1 {   
/// <summary>     
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml  
/// </summary>  
///
public partial class Window1 : Window  
{
     string fixedItem;
      public Window1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventHandler(list_changes);
      }
        private void list_changes(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         listBox1.UpdateLayout();
         listBox1.ScrollIntoView(fixedItem); 
    }
     // REST OF YOUR CODE...
```

**UPDATE**
If you meant your scrolling is right already, only moving the item to the last viewable position, I'd get the item from three (or more) indexes ahead in order to centralize the item on the listbox.

Comment: already tried this code, not working as i want, i dont want to move the item, I want it to stay in the exactly same position as I clicked it, others elements can change

Answer (score 0):

i've tested this in Silverlight but the difference is there

your code doesn't works

```
private void list_changes(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
{
      listBox1.ScrollIntoView(fixedItem);
}
```

but this code works !

```
private void list_changes(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
{
      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => listBox1.ScrollIntoView(fixedItem));
}
```

the problems comes from the tact that the listbox scrolls and then adds the new item so then REscroll..
if you call the scroll on the dispatcher, the listbox will finish its work adding items and THEN scroll to your item